# Create a tag for misbehaviors?

Tags: discussion, tags

That is, a tag when the main objective is to write infinite loops without doing useful things, to crash the compiler, to generate errors, to use a lot of memory, or to generate big executables, etc.

I feel those challenges are related, and a user who likes one of them may like the others. And currently they are likely only tagged as [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest).

Should we create a tag for them. And if so, what exactly should be included in this tag?

Comment: If such a tag existed, would you add it to your favorites and use it to find questions that you personally enjoy answering?

Comment: @Rainbolt I don't usually use the favorite feature. But I was just going to find some related questions, at least for finding whether a new idea would be a duplicate. And it wasn't easy. I had the idea for a tag when I came across this question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16036/25180 , which is unexpected for me to be existed. It's likely I wouldn't know it by keyword search if not accidentally.

Comment: I hadn't thought about using tags to search for duplicates. That seems useful. I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see why [misbehaviors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehaviors) would be a useful tag. If you wanted to write a challenge involving crashes, infinite loops, or other types of misbehaviors, you might use the tag to search for duplicates.

There is another tag called [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded). If you think about it, most questions using that tag are really just a combination of [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) and [misbehaviors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehaviors)*. I think we should split that tag into two. This would satisfy your request without increasing the total number of tags. There's no reason to have a more specialized version of popularity contest anyway.

Proposed actions:

- Retag all [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) challenges as [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) and [misbehaviors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehaviors)
- Delete the [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) tag
- Add the new [misbehaviors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehaviors) tag to any questions that it might apply to

<sub>*With few exceptions, notably [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31615/efficient-error-free-encoding)</sub>

Comment: No, [tag:underhanded] is for unexpected behaviors to the users. What I meant is to cause the language itself to do faulty things, and is in most cases expected by the users if they read the code. [tag:misbehaviors] might not be the best name for it.

Comment: Not all [tag:underhanded] questions are popcons. Or "misbehaviours".

Comment: @PeterTaylor The tag description reads "Votes reflect how non-obvious the bug is." Asking users to vote according to subjective rules sounds exactly like a popcon to me.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Why do you need separate tags for "unexpected behavior" and "faulty behavior"? I don't see the difference.

Comment: The code can be obviously having faulty behaviors. Examples are [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7197/25180) and maybe [my question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61115/25180). It isn't necessary to hide what you are doing. Maybe I didn't describe it well.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Only 8 questions are tagged underhanded but not popcon. One is closed. [One](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5334/18487) is essentially a popcon but with only two judges. [One](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45584/18487) is a combination of popcon and code golf. [This one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6666/18487) and [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24504/18487) are just mistagged and should be a popcon. The remaining three that are truly not a popcon fail to even adhere to the underhanded tag description.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Okay, so you want a tag for "faulty behaviors", and a separate tag for "unexpected faulty behaviors"? That seems unnecessarily specific. "Unexpected" is subjective, which automatically makes it a pop contest anyway.

Comment: @Rainbolt But expected faulty behaviors can be pop-con too.

Comment: Huh? I can't see how 24504 is a mistagged popcon: it's fairly explicit that it's correctly tagged [tag:code-golf]. And I'm not sure why you say that 31615 doesn't adhere to the [tag:underhanded] tag description. In fact, I think that latter question is probably the best question in the entire tag, both as a PPCG question and as a potential Underhanded C Contest question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor "Looks fishy" is definitely a subjective criteria, but code golf is a purely objective tag, so either there's a hole in the spec for 24504, or the question is mistagged. My mistake - 31615 does adhere to the tag description. Would you be satisfied if I said that *most* underhanded contests are just "pop contests" + "misbehaviors"? I edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Yes, a challenge about faulty behaviors can be a popcon. So what? What is the problem with tagging such a challenge "popularity-contest" plus "misbehavior"? Surely that describes any challenge that is a popcon involving misbehaviors (**expected or otherwise**).

Comment: Basically it just means whether it is automatically a pop-con is irrelevant. For the tag problem itself, I'm just waiting for other answers.

Comment: @jimmy23013 You aren't directly answering any of my questions. I asked what the problem was, and you said "It means that something is irrelevant." I asked why you needed separate tags twice now, and you avoided the question both times.

Comment: Let me try to explain my idea a little better. If you have a popcon about faulty behavior, tag it [misbehaviors] + [pop-con]. If you have a codegolf about faulty behavior, tag it [misbehaviors] + [code-golf]. If you have an underhanded contest, retag it depending on what kind of contest it is. About 90% will be retagged as [popcon] + [misbehavior], and maybe 10% will be retagged [code golf] or [code challenge] + [misbehavior]. Make sense now?

Comment: @Rainbolt I was trying to respond to your comment before the edit, which now I forgot about the exact content. But fine. "Misbehavior" isn't well-defined in this context. Literally it can mean not good behavior, or just unexpected behavior if somebody expect it to do something useful, which is subjective. It can be the user reading source code, the user being told the rationales, the careless programmer, the language API itself, or the user watching at the system monitor, etc, who doesn't expect it to behave as such. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) There can be hackers, trolls, sabotagers or whoever else who intended to make the program to do bad things, and expect the outcome to be bad, and thinks that's the right behavior. So it would be impractical to just define a group of questions about behaviors unexpected by a person of any kind. We already phased out the questions about misbehaviors at the perspective of a user being told a stupid rationale, which is different enough from the existing "underhanded". (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) And that had the same too-boring-to-explain reason about why the two groups of questions in context are different enough. Arguebly they were more close, as they are both for users trying to understand something, and not the API or monitor who can't think like a human. But practically all these are just bullshitting, as it is not important at all whether a specific challenge can be defined as underhanded, misbehavior or anything, but whether there is a practical need to separate them for the user looking for questions, and we can rename the tags if one of them is too general. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) You didn't address why you think nobody would want to separate them, just saying underhanded can be defined as a kind of misbehavior literally and technically, and I don't have evidence that many people do want to, either, and that's why I'm asking. So I'm saying all of those without a good reason. And that's why I didn't respond, if you really need a reason for that.

Comment: For simplicity, returning an error for the human to read for code that is supposed to not work, is a feature of a language, thus is usually expected and not underhanded at all. About whether underhanded is technically another kind of misbehavior, I don't care and don't think it is very relevant.