# Create the [error] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

We already asked [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7269/44713) on a tag for *misbehaviors*, but the tag [misbehaviors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehaviors) would only apply to popularity contests where the misbehavior wasn't easily seen (see: [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded)). However, there are quite a few contests that are involving errors as the full purpose of the challenge, not just as a slight of hand. I have compiled a short list below for examples:

- [Make an error quine!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36260/44713)
- [The Fatal Error Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41334/44713)
- [Make a slow error quine maker!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51007/44713)
- [Exit Code Golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107193/44713)
- [Shortest program that throws StackOverflow Error](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9359/44713)

These all need a tag to specify that they relate to errors and/or exceptions. I suggest that we make an [error](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) tag.

Comment: Why do they need a tag? They seem to have virtually nothing in common except for a keyword which would allow them to be found easily with the search functionality.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Because they have to do with the generation of errors in order to come to some goal? That's like saying we should burninate "number" because they're all unrelated in terms of algorithm or end goal.

Comment: I don't think even that vague description covers the second and fourth questions in the list. And fwiw: I have no objection to burninating number, which IMO is a useless tag.

Comment: Generation of errors is still output. We don't need a tag to distinguish between STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: @mbomb007 That's not the only distinction. Any form of error generation to achieve some goal (see: generating an exit code, generating a specific kind of error, etc.).

Comment: I know, but it's *all* output.

Comment: @mbomb007 But if we're not distinguishing between different causes of output, there's no reason to have _any_ tags unrelated to winning criteria.

Comment: I don't think there are enough cases where it'd be significantly interesting to use errors instead of not using them.

Comment: @mbomb007 This is relating to challenges, not answers, so I don't see the applicability of that comment to tags.

Comment: There are few reasons to create a *challenge* using errors instead of not using them. >.>

Answer (score 1):

We now have the [error-message](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-message) tag, which covers this in a much more objective way than [error](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error)